# Multiple staging areas

Tags: git

Can I have multiple staging areas or achieve a similar effect using git?

My typical work flow is along the lines of:

- work, work, work
- now I have an idea of something useful, let's commit it `git add -p`, `y`, `y`
- but first these smaller style changes: `git reset HEAD .`
- `git add -p`, `n`, `n`, `y`, `q`, `git commit -m "style changes"`
- `git add -p` .. commit the actual thing

Sometimes I have 20 smaller commits to make from a huge pile of changes. It would save me hours a day, if I could run through the patches like `git add -p` and then "dispatch" each patch to it's own staging area and commit each area separately.

Comment: Could you switch between local branches?

Comment: Not sure I understand? How would that help me avoid running through all patches for each commit?

Comment: I think I'm the one that's not understanding. Are you trying to set up a patch workflow like this? http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/patch-workflows

Comment: It sounds like you might also benefit from interactive rebasing- this will let you take an arbitrary set of (contiguous) commits and convert them into a different set of commits by rearranging and/or combining them.

Comment: @ABMagil I do this all the time :-) Sometimes I can get by with it, but it is _a lot_ more typing and bookkeeping.

Comment: Another option that might meet your needs (that I haven't used personally), Staged Git. It offers the ability to manage pushing/popping patches to/from a stack: http://www.procode.org/stgit/

Comment: Would be great to have more tools that supported this.  So far I found [this](http://ben.villagechief.com/2012/01/multiple-git-staging-areas.html) and [GitKraken](https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-git-gui-staging/)

Comment: I think a proper "extension" should be implemented like this:
-- 
Consider that git need to diff with stage to detect new change, a multistage should be built on top of original stage.
-- 
On staging, save the change to both git stage and multistage.
-- On commit, due to current limitation, stash all unstaged, stash the stage, 
commit one of the multistage. pop stash-of-stage, restage all changes, pop stage-of-unstaged.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit, 30 May 2020**: In Git 2.15 or later I recommend using `git worktree` instead of trying to do the below.  There are some restrictions on added work-trees that make them somewhat annoying for this kind of work-flow, but it *can* work, and is built in to modern Git.

Note that if you *do* do something like I describe below, `git gc` won't know to look in your alternate index files, and in fact, from its original introduction in Git 2.5 until it was fixed in Git 2.15, `git gc` forgot to check added work-trees and their index files!

See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382252/1256452) for more.

---

You can in fact have multiple different staging areas (more literally, multiple index files) in git.  To achieve the effect you want you would have to write your own variant of `git add -p` anyway, so what I will do here is sketch an outline, as it were, of how to do this.

The default index file—the one git uses if you don't direct it to some other index file—lives in `.git/index` (or, more shell-correctly, `$GIT_DIR/.index` where `$GIT_DIR` is taken from the environment or, if not set there, from `git rev-parse --git-dir`).

If you set the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, however, git will use that file instead as the index.  Thus, you might begin your "scatter changes to four branches" process by doing something like this:

```
GIT_DIR=${GIT_DIR:-$(git rev-parse --git-dir)} || exit 1
index_tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1
trap "rm -rf $index_tmp_dir" 0 1 2 3 15 # clean up on exit

# make four copies of initial staging area
for f in i1 i2 i3 i4; do
    cp $GIT_DIR/index $index_tmp_dir/$f
done

# THIS IS THE HARD PART:
# Now, using `git diff-files -p` or similar, get patches
# (diff hunks).
# Whenever you're ready to stage one, pick an index for it,
# then use:
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$index_tmp_dir/$which git apply --cached < diffhunk

# Once done, commit each index file separately with some
# variation on:
for f in i1 i2 i3 i4; do
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$index_tmp_dir/$which git commit
done
```

For the part labeled "hard part", your best bet might well be to copy git's add-interactive perl script, found in `$(git --exec-path)/git-add--interactive`, then modify it to suit.  To remove the "exactly four commits" restriction, make this modified interactive-add create a new index file dynamically (by copying the original, or perhaps creating an "empty" index equal to the `HEAD` commit or whatever; see `git read-tree` as well).

Edit: the *some variation on* section really should almost certainly use `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree` to make *new branches* out of each of these commits, using the parent of the current commit as their parent, rather than allowing `git commit` to string the commits together as a linear chain.  That means one must also choose some naming scheme for these various newly-created branches.

Comment: This is exactly the outcome I was looking for, I'm just surprised this is not more common to at least have a well know third party solution.
Is something about my work flow broken?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "broken" as much as "unusual".  And, not that I would claim any great success at it, but what I try to do is make a lot of tiny commits, both for the "main task at hand" and (separate commits but on the same temp branch) for small side fixes, which I can then split into different branches via `git cherry-pick` (and then clean up or discard the branch on which all the tiny commits were made).  (Which is the method you say is more bookkeeping, etc)

Comment: @ThomasJensen, imo this workflow is the only sane one.  it's not realistic to work on *exclusively* discrete logical chunks and then commit them.  you get into flow, as you're working on one file you notice something else, maybe as simple as old comments that require deleting.  an hour later and your index is full of disparate changes.  being able to `--patch` through them , shuttling each change off into an appropriate logical chunk, is precisely what you want most of the time.  it's shocking that it's not baked in functionality.

Comment: Same. This needs a proper solution. I can't for the life of me wean myself off this way of working!

Comment: Let's see if we can get some momentum going here: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2760

Comment: @Jonah, you don't have to work on locally discrete tasks to end up with logically discrete commits. You can amend, cherry-pick, `add -p`, and `rebase -i` to take your messy jumbled commits and split and combine them into a series that tells a clean, logical story.

Comment: It is 2023, is it implemented yet ? I was using Perforce until recently and I could have several changelists at the same time. Unfortunately Perforce is working per file and not per change.

Comment: When I have 30 modified files I would like to go through them only once. File per file, change per change, I would like to dispatch each change to its corresponding staging area. When all the changes have been dispatched I can commit all these staging areas. Now I have to go through all the files several times. Sometimes looking four times at the same change before it is its turn to be staged. It is stupid.

Answer (score 6):

[Git 2.5 introduced git worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) in July 2015, which allows for one clone, multiple working tree, in which you could isolate your various modifications.

But nowadays (Q4 2019), you would not be able to modify the `git-add--interactive.perl` for much longer, because with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git add -i`", which is getting rewritten in C, has been extended to cover subcommands other than the "`patch`".

(That rewrite is officially completed and made default in Git 2.37, Q3 2022. See the last section).

See [commit 2e697ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e697ced9d647d6998d70f010d582ba8019fe3af), [commit d763357](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7633578b5ecf0d75e2793b01aa2e9afe645c186), [commit 8746e07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8746e07277cb548185a33efa0037c313a06001f8), [commit ab1e1cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab1e1cccaf6252e2fb47b1bfbc5bc8d3d678bfe1), [commit c54ef5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c54ef5e4246f569b084db5b90bbb93c854bb0aa6), [commit a8c45be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8c45be939d88c2d1df88daf7958da2ee5dce170), [commit f37c226](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f37c22645408540cb03018f82a95fcd6ae6e4fbf), [commit c08171d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c08171d156f6f77bdab6500f0b433b650a31ccae), [commit 0c3944a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c3944a628e46f6abb1add20f19641c5bbef8a1a) (29 Nov 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3beff38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3beff388b2accbc474383d38ef12d4fe31152abc), 16 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`built-in add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8746e07277cb548185a33efa0037c313a06001f8): implement the `patch` command
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Well, it is not a full implementation yet. In the interest of making this easy to review (and easy to keep bugs out), we still hand off to the Perl script to do the actual work.
>
> The `patch` functionality actually makes up for more than half of the 1,800+ lines of `git-add--interactive.perl`. It will be ported from Perl to C incrementally, later.

Still in the context of rewriting git add in C: more test coverage update in preparation for further work on "`git add -i`".

See [commit b4bbbbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4bbbbd5a247e0e75d079bca591b657ec9084a46), [commit 89c8559](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c8559367aae771006cc0956b6f5e54cc8c614c), [commit e91162b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e91162be9ce7195309dc2b7e3c03988481cee850), [commit 0c3222c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c3222c4f322c586099d2773e180dabf6d4f6568), [commit 24be352](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24be352d52f96b2cace4d3e5f01f02917b7d649b), [commit 8539b46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8539b465341cc475f219ed46273a1c157bddafa0), [commit 0f0fba2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f0fba2cc87219bf0c182201b7798ceb74c24857) (06 Dec 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 011fc2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/011fc2e88e9ab13760c571330737ffaf0986e4ef), 16 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c8559367aae771006cc0956b6f5e54cc8c614c): use non-zero exit code when the diff generation failed
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> The first thing `git add -p` does is to generate a diff. If this diff cannot be generated, `git add -p` should not continue as if nothing happened, but instead fail.
>
> What we *actually* do here is much broader: we now verify for *every* `run_cmd_pipe()` call that the spawned process actually succeeded.
>
> Note that we have to change two callers in this patch, as we need to store the spawned process' output in a local variable, which means that the callers can no longer decide whether to interpret the `return <$fh>` in array or in scalar context.
>
> This bug was noticed while writing a test case for the diff.algorithm feature, and we let that test case double as a regression test for this fixed bug, too.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), The effort to move "`git-add--interactive`" to C continues.

See [commit 2e40831](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e4083198d1508206488af4c82093ceb6cf20f4e), [commit 54d9d9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54d9d9b2eebe1c8f8b54626f98a5e1414ce766ba), [commit ade246e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ade246efed509a68348901e7a085ceb55915bfea), [commit d6cf873](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6cf873340703098f2d7f54be457e4db1b32cf7b), [commit 9254bdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9254bdfb4f971be4be5364341a0387e8a1f3734a), [commit bcdd297](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcdd297b782b19782d8e09b18682ec61d7c36897), [commit b38dd9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b38dd9e7151f118b989f8c9851bc38a8a8733eaf), [commit 11f2c0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11f2c0dae8f8889b533455d700121d437f4be19f), [commit 510aeca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/510aeca199c4feeb38d318cc151ecf5464a3a865), [commit 0ecd9d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ecd9d27fc3b38c19cf75d7cad98d0120adb7383), [commit 5906d5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5906d5de77628e956d708e9a1796c12bee316b59), [commit 47dc4fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47dc4fd5eb4ab8fbe8ea6bb10e35d398da991cea), [commit 80399ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80399aec5ab4dbcc4f3f964da4169174f1e0024e), [commit 7584dd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7584dd3c66012e327f9cd7589d4f95ab2373cd47), [commit 12c24cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12c24cf850d280dd08dfe7361603b7089007fe3a), [commit 25ea47a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25ea47af494c5ec086aae102d358c4001c9a1459), [commit e3bd11b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3bd11b4ebed7dd6fd0cccc6765be64f76cc5766), [commit 1942ee4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1942ee44e8b1715a2e0555a0ea432ea6ab488f4e), [commit f6aa7ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6aa7ecc34373f32621b05659d5d2447d690be18) (13 Dec 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 45b96a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45b96a6fa1ce2009f82d2ea1698b49fda0c11169), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`built-in add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcdd297b782b19782d8e09b18682ec61d7c36897): implement hunk editing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Just like `git add --edit` allows the user to edit the diff before it is being applied to the index, this feature allows the user to edit the diff *hunk*.
>
> Naturally, it gets a bit more complicated here because the result has to play well with the remaining hunks of the overall diff. Therefore, we have to do a loop in which we let the user edit the hunk, then test whether the result would work, and if not, drop the edits and let the user decide whether to try editing the hunk again.
>
> Note: in contrast to the Perl version, we use the same diff "coalescing" (i.e. merging overlapping hunks into a single one) also for the check after editing, and we introduce a new flag for that purpose that asks the `reassemble_patch()` function to pretend that all hunks were selected for use.
>
> This allows us to continue to run `git apply` *without* the `--allow-overlap` option (unlike the Perl version), and it also fixes two known breakages in `t3701-add-interactive.sh` (which we cannot mark as resolved so far because the Perl script version is still the default and continues to have those breakages).

And:

> ### [`built-in add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11f2c0dae8f8889b533455d700121d437f4be19f): coalesce hunks after splitting them
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> This is considered "the right thing to do", according to [933e44d3a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/933e44d3a040c41a1e45d53a416edd107cc3ae0a) ("`add -p`": work-around an old laziness that does not coalesce hunks, 2011-04-06, Git v1.7.5.2).
>
> Note: we cannot simply modify the hunks while merging them; Once we implement hunk editing, we will call `reassemble_patch()` whenever a hunk is edited, therefore we must not modify the hunks (because the user might e.g. hit `K` and change their mind whether to stage the previous hunk).

And:

> ### [`built-in add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6aa7ecc34373f32621b05659d5d2447d690be18): start implementing the `patch` functionality in C
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> In the previous steps, we re-implemented the main loop of `git add -i` in C, and most of the commands.
>
> Notably, we left out the actual functionality of `patch`, as the relevant code makes up more than half of `git-add--interactive.perl`, and is actually pretty independent of the rest of the commands.
>
> With this commit, we start to tackle that `patch` part. For better separation of concerns, we keep the code in a separate file, [`add-patch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f6aa7ecc34373f32621b05659d5d2447d690be18/add-patch.c). The new code is still guarded behind the `add.interactive.useBuiltin` config setting, and for the moment, it can only be called via `git add -p`.
>
> The actual functionality follows the original implementation of [5cde71d64aff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cde71d64aff03d305099b4d239552679ecfaab6) ("[`git add --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---interactive)", 2006-12-10, Git v1.5.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f38e0372266b5d674972e7039f8bd4156589558)), but not too closely (for example, we use string offsets rather than copying strings around, and after seeing whether the `k` and `j` commands are applicable, in the C version we remember which previous/next hunk was undecided, and use it rather than looking again when the user asked to jump).
>
> As a further deviation from that commit, We also use a comma instead of a slash to separate the available commands in the prompt, as the current version of the Perl script does this, and we also add a line about the question mark ("print help") to the help text.
>
> While it is tempting to use this conversion of `git add -p` as an excuse to work on `apply_all_patches()` so that it does *not* want to read a file from `stdin` or from a file, but accepts, say, an `strbuf` instead, we will refrain from this particular rabbit hole at this stage.

The conclusion of that rewriting effort is found with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020): the "`add -i`/`-p`" machinery has been written in C but it is not used by default yet.
It is made default to those who are participating in **`feature.experimental`** experiment.

See [commit 2df2d81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df2d81ddd068cf2e8a65743b258d0a263b84ae6) (08 Sep 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e96b271](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e96b271d185b59d93f7deab454a788c9d8dd0e50), 18 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df2d81ddd068cf2e8a65743b258d0a263b84ae6): use the built-in version when `feature.experimental` is set
>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> We have had parallel implementations of "`add -i`/`-p`" since 2.25 and have been using them from various codepaths since 2.26 days, but never made the built-in version the default.
>
> We have found and fixed a handful of corner case bugs in the built-in version, and it may be a good time to start switching over the user base from the scripted version to the built-in version.
>
> Let's enable the built-in version for those who opt into the `feature.experimental` guinea-pig program to give wider exposure.

And, still with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), an "`add -i`/`-p`" fix:

See [commit 1c6ffb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c6ffb546bf5d31c2cef2fefc86317658fda59e0), [commit dc62641](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc6264157236fb729ad072e18f14d89549c08555) (07 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 694e517](https://github.com/git/git/commit/694e517778243256b748819cc60eff6011238a0a), 18 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`add-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc6264157236fb729ad072e18f14d89549c08555): fix inverted return code of `repo_read_index()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> After applying hunks to a file with "`add -p`", the C `patch_update_file()` function tries to refresh the index (just like the Perl version does).
> We can only refresh the index if we're able to read it in, so we first check the return value of `repo_read_index()`.
> But unlike many functions, where "0" is success, that function is documented to return the number of entries in the index.
> Hence we should be checking for success with a non-negative return value.
>
> Neither the tests nor any users seem to have noticed this, probably due to a combination of:
>
> - this affects only the C version, which is not yet the default
> - following it up with any porcelain command like "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dc6264157236fb729ad072e18f14d89549c08555/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> or "`git commit`" would refresh the index automatically.
>
> But you can see the problem by running the plumbing "[`git diff-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dc6264157236fb729ad072e18f14d89549c08555/Documentation/git-diff-files.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-files))</sup> immediately after "`add -p`" stages all hunks.
> Running the new test with `GIT_TEST_ADD_I_USE_BUILTIN=1` fails without the matching code change.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), "[`git add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fc1879839242dbb1a378888b68493cbb04b07e0/Documentation/git-add.txt#L89)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--i))</sup> was rewritten in C some time ago and has been in testing; the reimplementation is now exposed to general public **by default**.

See [commit 0527ccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8), [commit ed922dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed922dcab6ac3e2cc0a53f06e9044ba180ea0675) (30 Nov 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1fc1879](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fc1879839242dbb1a378888b68493cbb04b07e0), 30 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8): default to the built-in implementation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [9a5315e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a5315edfdf662c4d9bf444ebc297bc802fa5e04) ("Merge branch 'js/patch-mode-in-others-in-c'", 2020-02-05, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a5315edfdf662c4d9bf444ebc297bc802fa5e04) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de93cc14ab7e8db7645d8dbe4fd2603f76d5851f)), Git acquired a built-in implementation of [`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup>'s interactive mode that could be turned on via the config option `add.interactive.useBuiltin`.
>
> The first official Git version to support this knob was v2.26.0.
>
> In [2df2d81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df2d81ddd068cf2e8a65743b258d0a263b84ae6) ("add -i: use the built-in version when feature.experimental is set", 2020-09-08, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e96b271d185b59d93f7deab454a788c9d8dd0e50) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/385c171a018f2747b329bcfa6be8eda1709e5abd)), this built-in implementation was also enabled via `feature.experimental`.
> The first version with this change was v2.29.0.
>
> More than a year (and very few bug reports) later, it is time to declare the built-in implementation mature and to turn it on by default.
>
> We specifically leave the `add.interactive.useBuiltin` configuration in place, to give users an "escape hatch" in the unexpected case should they encounter a previously undetected bug in that implementation.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8/Documentation/config/add.txt#L10-L12):

> Set to `false` to fall back to the original Perl implementation of
> the interactive version of [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) instead of the built-in
> version.
> **Is `true` by default**.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), finally retire the scripted "[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/06bca9708ac86d286a6f5265ff0e6c532f44c657/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> -p/-i implementation and have everybody use the one reimplemented in C.

See [commit 5a7d41d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a7d41d849290ceadb02487ec962c5a040391535), [commit d21878f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d21878f073043b9205f5049f1cd53560d67b9f3f), [commit 20b813d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20b813d7d3dc576aa58de22da2450b49116945bf) (06 Feb 2023) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 06bca97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06bca9708ac86d286a6f5265ff0e6c532f44c657), 15 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20b813d7d3dc576aa58de22da2450b49116945bf): remove "add.interactive.useBuiltin" & Perl "git add--interactive"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Since [commit 0527ccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8) (`add -i`: default to the built-in implementation, 2021-11-30, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fc1879839242dbb1a378888b68493cbb04b07e0) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bcf4f6271ad8c952739164d160e97efd579424f)) (`add -i`: default to the built-in implementation, first released with Git v2.37.0 the built-in version of "`add -i`" has been the default.
>
> That built-in implementation was added in [commit f83dff6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f83dff60a7880f1abfc3dc3c6b8e2972c4889da5) (Start to implement a built-in version of `git add --interactive`, 2019-11-13, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7998d979322c439578a4334524ae2c924042705) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/083378cc35c4dbcc607e4cdd24a5fca440163d17)) (Start to implement a built-in version of [`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20b813d7d3dc576aa58de22da2450b49116945bf/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup>, first released with Git v2.25.0.
>
> At this point enough time has passed to allow for finding any remaining bugs in this new implementation, so let's remove the fallback code.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20b813d7d3dc576aa58de22da2450b49116945bf/Documentation/config/add.txt#L10-L13):

> ### `add.interactive.useBuiltin`
>
> Unused configuration variable.
>
> Used in Git versions v2.25.0 to v2.36.0 to enable the built-in version of [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)'s
> interactive mode, which then became the default in Git
> versions v2.37.0 to v2.39.0.