# Can't use "Git add -i"

Tags: git, perl

Trying to patch a file to last commit, so I run "`git add -p`" and "`git add -i`", but received the following error:

[image: Output]

That is:

```sh
D:\Working\test>git add-i
      0 [main] perl 375 child_copy: stack write copy failed, 6xFFFFC480..8x10000000e, done 6444523849, windows pid 15080, Win32 error 5
      [main] perl 375 child_copy: stack write copy failed, exFFFFC480..9x1000eeeee, done 6444523049, windows pid 15880, Win32 error 5
    481 [main) perl 375 dofork: child 376 - pid 13800, exitval ex183, errno 11 
     Can't fork, trying again in 5 seconds at C:/Program Files/Git/ming64/share/per15/Git.pm line 1647.
     main) perl 375 dofork: child 377 pid 4888, exitval ex103, errno 11 Can't fork, trying again in 5 seconds at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/per15/Git.pm line 1647.

D:\Working\test>git add -p
    0 [main] perl 9 child_copy: stack write copy failed, exFFFFC460..ex1eeeeeeee, done 6444523849, windows pid 7892, Min32 error S ses [main] perl 9 dofork: child 10 pid 11876, exitval ex183, errno 11
    Can't fork, trying again in 5 seconds at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/per15/Git.pm line 1647. 5033325 [main] perl 9 child 
     copy: stack write copy failed, exFFFFC460..9x100000000, done 6444523849, windows pid 7892, Win32 error 5 5033826 [main] perl 9 dofork: child 11 - pid 12220, exitval ex103, errno 11 Can't fork, trying again in 5 seconds at C:/Program Files/Git/ming 64/share/per15/it.pm line 1647.
```

Tried to uninstall and install Git, but the issue still persist.

Comment: `git add -i` and `git add -p` are Perl scripts; it looks like your Perl language interpreter is mis-installed or broken.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: Thanks to comment of @torek, I managed to use the commands after installing Perl.

Comment: @torek, Re "*it looks like your Perl language interpreter is mis-installed or broken.*" , That's not true. According to the error message, `perl` was successfully executing. It also indicates that the problem wasn't originating from Perl; the problem was originating from the OS emulation's `fork` emulation.

Comment: @ikegami - Perl was partly running, but failing; on Windows, that usually means some sort of DLL issue, I believe. (As VonC noted in the answer, one can also just update to the current Git, in which some parts of this are now in C.)

Comment: @torek, First of all, it wasn't failing on Windows, it was failing int he MSYS unix emulation. Windows doesn't even have a fork. // And while the rest may be true, it doesn't change what I said. The problem was in MSYS itself, not perl. The language of choice didn't matter. If a C program in MSYS were to use fork, it would have had exactly the same problem. So I repeat: the problem had nothing to do with Perl, contrary to what you said.

Comment: And ... does not "msys emulation" count as "software that's run on Windows"? I wouldn't know all the ins and outs here, as I studiously *avoid* Windows, but to outsiders, everything that you run on a Windows system either *is* "Windows" or is "on Windows". Would you say that git.exe doesn't run "on Windows"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thanks to comment of @torek, I managed to use the commands after installing Per

You should not have.

1. The latest versions of [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) no longer use Perl for `git add`  (`mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-add.exe`). This is [rewritten in C since Git 2.25, Q1 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275886/6309).
2. `perl.exe` is part of the Git for Windows distribution: make sure your `%PATH%` includes `C:\path\to\Git\usr\bin`

There is no need to install Perl for Git to run.

---

2 years later (Q1 2022), With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), there are still finishing touches to C rewrite of "[`git add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d7234921273fd55ce33d44ae2735645650800870/Documentation/git-add.txt#L89)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--i))</sup> in single-key interactive mode.

See [commit 0f584de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f584debc74afefdd24449136ffb2c77859e38c9), [commit 6606d99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6606d99bae4161289d498b51a21acd11aa09e6ef), [commit e4938ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4938ce3cc5967c2366db289ca854b0b796a5afd), [commit 02af15d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02af15dec5bf0114b03c4c3bec5d8f60890a1c58) (16 Mar 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
See [commit 32f3ac2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32f3ac26e03c02d4085a2734a4eeb549852ade8d) (09 Mar 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d723492](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7234921273fd55ce33d44ae2735645650800870), 30 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`terminal`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f584debc74afefdd24449136ffb2c77859e38c9): restore settings on SIGTSTP
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> If the user suspends git while it is waiting for a keypress reset the terminal before stopping and restore the settings when git resumes.
> If the user tries to resume in the background print an error message (taking care to use async safe functions) before stopping again.
> Ideally we would reprint the prompt for the user when git resumes but this patch just restarts the `read()`.
>
> The signal handler is established with `sigaction()` rather than using `sigchain_push()` as this allows us to control the signal mask when the handler is invoked and ensure `SA_RESTART` is used to restart the read() when resuming.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the installation of Perl does help configure the %PATH% variable.

Comment: Do you know when the `git add -p` conversion is supposed to be finished? It's been quite a while for that one...

Comment: @torek I don't, and did not see much after Git 2.29: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382252/6309