# Skip past (full) staging area and commit file or patch directly?

Tags: git, git-commit

Imagine this scenario: you're working on a feature that requires touching lots of files, and you've got a lot of things staged, and a lot of things not staged (like debugging code, temporary comments for yourself to remember to do/undo certain things and not forget to add bits that you didn't yet have time to add), and then you see a simple one-line change that you must make, but which belongs in its own commit.

Is there any way to simply commit that without pulling everything out of the staging area that you've meticulously added, without stashing (and risking losing your careful selections of what to stage and what not to stage) and *just commit that one line*?

I realize that fiddling with [multiple staging areas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28947201/241142) would probably make this possible, but I'm hoping there is a simpler solution than that.  Some switch that lets me skip the staging area would be more convenient than mucking about with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to have 2 of them.

My ideal solution would be something sort of like this:

```
git commit --skip-stage --patch ./app/models/whatever.rb
```

If this is *impossible*, then I will simply stash and use `--index` when I pop it back, and hope I didn't accidentally do something between stashing and popping that breaks the ability to cleanly restore the index.

Because I know someone will wonder "if you know about `--index` with `git stash pop`, why are you asking this question?  Because it is as much about pushing the envelope of what I can do with Git as it is about solving a practical problem.  Just because one solution to a problem exists doesn't mean it is the best solution or that one should stop looking for alternatives.  That applies to all of life, not just Git.

Comment: You don't want to "skip" the staging area - per se - the index contains the current state of HEAD plus any staged stages.  So skipping the staging area and creating a commit (without updating those changes in the index) would mean that you'd actually have a staged removal of the changes you just committed immediately after you've done the commit.  (But this is a minor complaint about terminology; I understand what you're asking and it's an excellent question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `-a` flag, `git commit -a`, and the `--only` and `--include` flags (which can be shortened to `-o` and `-i`) that allow you to do:

```
git commit --only file1 file2
```

or:

```
git commit --include file3
```

but these work *by* creating a new temporary index, as I outlined in my answer to your linked question.

What these do is a little bit magic, and may or may not be what you want.  In particular, the temporary index file(s) that these create include `.git/index.lock`, which is Git's internal temporary *new* index, which—if the commit succeeds—will become *the* (regular) index afterward.  This has a some very powerful (and somewhat peculiar) consequences.  Let's look at each mode of operation.  The `--only` variant comes close to what you want, and might sometimes *be* what you want, but might sometimes destroy something valuable.

#### `git commit --only file1 file2`

This starts by making a new temporary index that is copied from `HEAD`.  Into this new temporary index, Git copies `file1` and `file2` from the work-tree, as if by `git add file1 file2`.  So now this temporary index matches `HEAD` except for the two named files.

Git also creates `.git/index.lock` by copying the current index contents, i.e., the staged files.  Into *this* temporary index, Git copies `file1` and `file2` as before.  So *this* temporary index—which is different from the first one—has all your staged files except that `file1` and `file2` are overwritten from the work-tree.

Now Git makes a new commit, using the *first* temporary index—the one that mostly matches `HEAD`, except for the two files.  If this commit succeeds, Git updates the current branch as usual, then removes this first temporary index, and unlocks and updates the real / regular index by renaming the *second* temporary index, `.git/index.lock`, to `.git/index`.  So now the normal index is the way it was before *except* that `file1` and `file2` have been replaced in it, as if by `git add file1 file2`.

If you had carefully staged a *different* version of `file1` and/or `file2`, which are (of course) not in your work-tree right now—because the work-tree versions are the ones you're committing with `--only`—that special version is *gone*, wiped out by the `git add` step.  If not, this is probably what you wanted!

#### `git commit --include file3`

Here, let's assume that you've `git add`ed `file1` earlier—perhaps a slightly different *version* of `file1` than is now in your work-tree, so that `file1` in the real / regular index differs from `file1` in `HEAD`.

Git starts by making a new temporary index named `.git/index.lock`, copied from the real / regular index.  Then, Git copies `file3` into this temporary index, as if by `git add file3`.

Now Git makes a new commit, using the temporary `.git/index.lock` index.  If this commit succeeds, Git updates the current branch as usual, then renames the temporary index from `.git/index.lock` to `.git/index`.  So now the real / regular index still has the `file1` you added earlier (which perhaps doesn't match the `file1` in the work-tree but is different from the old commit's `file1`), plus the `file3` you added via `git commit --include`.

(This mode never destroys any carefully-staged files, but also doesn't do what you describe in your question.)

Comment: This is an incredibly detailed answer!  If I understand correctly, this can be summed up as follows with regard to committing full files (all changes in any given file).  Both `--only` and `--include` ignore untracked files, but `--include` commits staged files _plus_ what you mention on the command line, while `--only` ignores staged files and only commits what you mention on the command line.  It seems to me that `--only` is _exactly_ what I'm looking for, but perhaps I didn't understand all the details in your answer.  (I'll test later with partial files and re-read your answer.)