# Find out staged files in git `pre-commit` hook when using `git commit -a`

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

I'm using a `git` `pre-commit` hook to automatically format all of my staged files. I'm determining the staged files via `git diff --name-only --cached` and then call a script on those files.
This all works well in the standard use case, however it doesn't work when I commit via

```
git commit -a ..
```

because the files are not yet staged.

Is there some way to:

1. Run the `-a` effect (add files to staging area) before the `pre-commit` hook?
2. Find out that the pre-commit runs in a `-a` commit?

There must be a way to handle this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> because the files are not yet staged

This actually isn't quite true.  But it's not quite false either.

Here is a (silly, meant for illustration only) pre-commit hook to demonstrate the problem:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#! /bin/sh
echo \$GIT_INDEX_FILE = $GIT_INDEX_FILE
git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD
exit 1
```

This hook uses the correct (from a reliability perspective anyway) command, `git diff-index --cached HEAD`, to find the names of staged files.  First, though, it prints the name of the index that is being used to commit the files.  (Last, it prevents the commit, since I don't really want to commit any of this.)

I made this executable (in a Git repository for Git itself), and modified a few files without `git add`ing them:

```
$ git status --short
 M Makefile
 M wt-status.c
```

(note that the `M`s are in the second column).  Then:

```
$ git commit
$GIT_INDEX_FILE = .git/index
$ git commit -a
$GIT_INDEX_FILE = [redacted]/.git/index.lock
Makefile
wt-status.c
```

The first hook invocation's `echo` tells us that we're using the real (main) index, and its `git diff-index` produces no output.

The second invocation tells us that we're using an alternate index file, named `.git/index.lock` (I trimmed away my source path).  It shows two staged files.

Let's go on to do one more thing: I'll `git add` the modified `Makefile` and make a second change to `Makefile`.  Now we have:

```
$ git status --short
MM Makefile
 M wt-status.c
```

The first line shows us that `HEAD:Makefile` (in the commit, frozen) differs from `:Makefile` (in the index, staged) which differs from `Makefile` (in the work-tree, unstaged), and indeed, we can see the three files are different:

```
$ git show HEAD:Makefile | head -2
# The default target of this Makefile is...
all::
$ git show :Makefile | head -2
#
# The default target of this Makefile is...
$ head -2 Makefile
# different
# The default target of this Makefile is...
```

Running `git commit` vs `git commit -a` now produces:

```
$ git commit
$GIT_INDEX_FILE = .git/index
Makefile
$ git commit -a
$GIT_INDEX_FILE = [redacted]/.git/index.lock
Makefile
wt-status.c
```

If I had not prevented the non-`-a` version of `git commit`, what *would* have been committed by `git commit` is the version of `Makefile` in the (main / real / `.git/index`) index, not the version in the work-tree.  Hence, if you want to inspect files that would be committed, you should look in the index.  You can use `git checkout-index` to extract files *from* the index, but be careful not to clobber work-tree versions, which may differ.

What would have been committed by `git commit -a` is the version of the Makefile in the work-tree, which Git already added to the (non-standard, temporary) `.git/index.lock` index.  Once the `git commit -a` finished, that non-standard temporary index would become the real index, destroying my intermediate, special staged copy of `Makefile`.  Again, to inspect files that would be committed, look in the index—using the redirected index, as Git will automatically, for both `git diff-index` and `git checkout-index`.

(Since I don't know quite what your script needs, I can't make particular recommendations for exactly how to use `git checkout-index` to extract the files of interest.  Consider using `--work-tree=` and a temporary directory, though.)

(See also my answer to [Skip past (full) staging area and commit file or patch directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54317749/1256452), which discusses just what `-a`, `--only`, and `--include` really do internally.)

Comment: This is a phenomenal response, even 4 years later has helped me make sense of things many many times. Thank you!